# how to find different elements in an array and put them into another array? c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to find different elements in an array and put them into another array.
For example:

```
A[0] = "Group1"
A[1] = "Group2"
A[2] = "Group1"
A[3] = "Group2"
A[4] = "Group3"
```

and I need another array to be:

```
B[0] = "Group1"
B[1] = "Group2"
B[2] = "Group3"
```

order of groups doesn't matter.
I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks!

Comment: Create a `set<string>` called `seen` and add all elements visited to `seen`. You can then skip elements that have already been seen when building your array `B`.

Comment: for small arrays go with `sort` + `unique`.

Comment: This question is massively understated. We can sort of guess that you want to copy _unique_ elements from an array into another array, but can you make this clear please?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array as a copy of the first, and then sort and use `std::unique` to eliminate duplicates:

```
std::vector<std::string> A {  ... };
std::vector<std::string> B( A );
std::sort( B.begin(), B.end() );
B.erase( std::unique( B.begin(), B.end() ), B.end() );
```

Another solution would be to use `std::unordered_set` as a second container and just copy all elements to there:

```
std::vector<std::string> A {  ... };
std::unordered_set<std::string> B( A.begin(), A.end() );
```

You may want to use `std::unordered_set` as a temporary container and copy from it to array B afterwards:

```
std::vector<std::string> A {  ... };
std::unordered_set<std::string> tmp( A.begin(), A.end() );
std::vector<std::string> B( tmp.begin(), tmp.end() );
```

You can also use `std::set` instead if you want your unique elements to be sorted, but that generally less effective solution.

It is difficult to say more as you provided not enough information - what type of arrays you use etc.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: erase-unique does - but only if they're consecutive

Comment: @Slava: You'd need to sort the vector first. Adding the lot into a set is definitely the proper solution.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I like to give *hints*. and yes, I was reffering to that.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Suggesting a modern container _is_ a must, since you don't know at compile-time what the size of the result is going to be, and because it would be professionally irresponsible not to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: how do you know that it's not available at compile-time?

Comment: sidenote: are the developers of your favorite libraries who use naked new, macros and fixed size arrays also professionally irresponsible?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Because if you knew your inputs to this algorithm at compile-time then you wouldn't have baked in an array with duplicates in the first place, or you would have generated the duplicateless version during the build.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: No, but those people are not posting on Stack Overflow asking how to do basic algorithms. And, in fact, even those people — barring stdlib implementers — ought not to be doing the things you say. I thought this was common knowledge by now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: if by "common knowledge" you refer to blindly following rules without realizing that the world is not black and white - yes, unfortunately they became common knowledge.... Look, I don't care if you suggest using containers, in fact, I very much *like* it. Just don't say it is a *must*.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: No, that's not what I refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem domain isn't clear. I assume you can use STL. Therefore, you may need one of the following *associative container* classes:

- `std::set`
- `std::map`
- `std::multiset`
- `std::multimap`
- `std::unordered_set`
- `std::unordered_map`